# Buying a large shed to use for a climate controlled workshop, what insulation options do I have?

Tags: insulation, shed, workshop

I'm going to get a prebuilt shed and I want to use it for a workshop so I want it climate controlled (I live in New England). Before I order I want to make sure I get anything I need added on (house wrap) so I'm ready to add insulation once it's installed. They offer house wrap and an R10 insulated floor as options but other than that what should I consider?

Soffit vents? 2x6 walls?

Should I plan on adding a ceiling and venting the roof or just try to put some foam insulation under the floor sheathing? Should I add a vapor barrier on the inside of the walls before I put up plywood?

[image: example shed]

Comment: Would use a ceiling unless you really need the extra height.  Unless you burn your own wood for heating, would have 2x6 walls and vapour barrier, cuts down on air leaks anyway.   Vent the roof and insulate the ceiling.  New England go for R 40 ceiling/ R 20 walls or better.

Comment: How much are you going to use it (in the winter), and how will it be heated?

Comment: Insulated sheathing on the exterior under the finish siding has the advantage of adding insulation that does not take up interior room in a small space and with covers the poor insulation of the studs. Wide plates and offset studs is a different option but takes up interior space. Stops the stud leak path by making interior and exterior studs separate. You can also use sheet insulation over the studs on the inside before the finished wall surface (drywall or perhaps plywood for a shop.) You may also want better doors and windows than "stock shed" would use.

Comment: We designed our house with 20cm insulation for the floor, 30cm in the walls and 50 in the roof. Heated by solar and 2 metres cubed of wood per year.